# How to make localhost(XAMPP) accessible from any computer?

Tags: web-services, networking, xampp, localhost

I'm using XAMPP, for development purposes
Is it possible to allow access from other computers outside network?

What do i need to configure?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using WAMPServer 2.5!

This means you are using Apache 2.4

In Apache 2.4 the syntax changed from what you are looking for to:

```
 Require local  ( For 127.0.0.1 and localhost and ::1 )
```

So you need to change that to allow access from anywhere to :

```
 Require all granted
```

And other changes as well, [you could always try reading the manual, radical I know, but it just may catch on.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html)